# Disparate database replication (between different types of RDBMS)

Tags: replication, database-replication

I'm looking for a recommendation for a product that enables replication between different database systems. We're just looking for standard replication (copy this table over here and apply transactions as they happen) - nothing fancy.

We can't use built-in database replication because our source server (Tandem/NSK) doesn't support any kind of push replication at all. We've been using GoldenGate (http://www.goldengate.com/), but I'm interested in other choices out there. If it matters, out destination server is an MSSQL box.

I know it gets expensive, so I'm not just interested in free products, and I'd prefer something with professional support. If you have some experience with a product like GoldenGate, I'd love to hear it, as I imagine there have to be other products on the market that do what GoldenGate does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SymmetricDS](http://symmetricds.org) might be a solution you would be interested in.  It synchronizes different types of RDBMSs, but it does use database triggers and is Java based.  It was built for more of a highly distributed and possible disconnected environment, but would work for point to point type replication.

Comment: Looks like there aren't many options out there - at least that people know about or that I can find online. We've stuck with Goldengate for now.